# Ubuntu. error opening directory no such device or directory

Tags: linux, windows

Делал загрузочную флешку с Windows PE, выскачила ошибка в процессе форматирвания и ноут перестал ее видеть. (Хотя в панели устройств отображался как диск с RAW-файловой системой.)

На винде не получилось отформатировать ее ни через проводник, ни через diskpart - всегда ошибкой заканчивалось дело.

Решил форматнуть через Ubuntu. Сделал другую загрeзочную флешку на Ubuntu - запустился через нее и подключил, ту которая не форматируется в винде. Но Ubuntu через:

```
lsblk
```

Сначала отображает 2ую флешку, как **sdb->sdb1**, но спустя некоторое время не видит ее.

Хотел форматнуть через **Gparted**, но он при сканировании sdb выдает ошибку:

```
error opening /dev/sdb: No such device or addres
```

Что делать? Выкидывать флешку или еще можно ее реанимировать?

Comment: похоже, что флешка просто выдохлась. К сожалению, такое бывает. Возможно, это случилось из-за процесса вставки. Что делать - почитать вывод dmesg, там бывают полезные сообщения. Второе - поискать утилиты для флешек от производителя.

Comment: если так то не повезло вдвойне =( и загрузчик винды накрылся и флеха сдохла...

Comment: Тыкал флэшку в морду системника или в зад?

Comment: @don Rumata, тыкал и в морду и в зад =)) Везде одинаковая реакция - первые секунд 10-20 видит **sdb**, а потом не видит....

Comment: А если кинуть флэшку в морозилку минут на 30 - 10-20 секунд превратятся хотя бы в минуту?